# Foreach statement with making new rows in bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an array of 4 items and it comes with display order. I need to have a row for the first two items, `(col-md-6)` split and then the other 2 the same.

Although my code seems to have the first item by itself, the middle ones are correct, and last one is by itself.

```
@foreach ($reviews as $review)
    @if ($review->displayOrder == 1 || $review->displayOrder == 3)
        <div class="row">
    @endif


        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="mb-30">
              <div class="ts4-text-cont">
                {{ $review->body }} - <strong><i>{{$review->name}}</i></strong>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    @if ($review->displayOrder == 1 || $review->displayOrder == 3)
        </div>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: $review->displayOrder == 1 represents item1 ?

Comment: can you post your html and css purely after laravel processing? as this information is not enough.